# C# Recurrant / Circular Navigation Best Practice

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice

Consider a C# application with the pages `A`, `B`, and `C` and the following flow.

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> A
A -> B
...
```

I'm currently navigating using this line of code in each page.

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new B());
```

A few questions.

1. Is it appropriate to have circular navigation which continually instantiates new pages? Or should I create singleton instances of the pages and navigate between those?
2. If creating new instances is OK, how do I clear out old pages? I don't need to support navigating backwards.
3. If I should create singleton instances, where should those be put?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would always instantiate UI each time the user navigates, but I might retain state in the viewmodel which is presented to that piece of UI.
I use Usercontrols rather than pages and mostly navigate using viewmodel first templating of the content in a contentcontrol.

1) Depends if you need to retain state. And if that state is purely ui if you're using mvvm.

2) Use a different method to navigate if you want fine control over when things are instantiated.

3) In a dictionary. Keyed by type.